# How to update EC2 instance after pushing new image version

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, docker-image

Currently I have a docker container running an image from an ECR repository.

After doing the push commands to the repository, the image is updated successfully, however, the EC2 instance still runs the previous docker image.

I followed this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/update-service.html to update the Container Service and do a **Force new deployment** but no update when I visit the container URL.

Am I missing something in the process of deployment and updating a container image? Or probably I have to create a New Task Definition or re-run the current one?

**UPDATE**
Going to my ECS service I see that the most recent deployment has 0  in the running count. Any way to update from here?

[image]

Comment: Not sure how you configure your TaskDefinition, I am guessing that you configure with `latest` tag. If yes, you might need to change the configure to all pull images. If this is not the case, you need to create new TaskDefinition. Cross check if there is any failure for new image as well.

Comment: I did not configure the image with `latest`. Instead I used something like `v1.0.0`. Does that mean that tagging with `latest` triggers the update to the instance after pushing the new version?

Comment: Not release, need need to tag the image upon pushing as well. The same image can have multiple tags, so in your case, `v1.0.1` can be tagged as `latest`. And make sure your TaskDefinition is pointing to latest, and enabled allwaysPull option.

Comment: well after doing `docker build -t <image>:release .`  I push with the same tag and version. `docker push <image>:release`

Is that what you are saying?

Comment: if I go to Clusters and click on the Service and then go to the Events tab I found this: 

`service ***** was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance ****** is already using a port required by your task. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section.`

Comment: This might be another issue, i assume you are using host port mapping.

Comment: yes I am doing 80:80

Comment: I just re-deployed and works fine. What I did was stop the Task in the cluster and then run it again. I am still looking for a way to be automatic after image is pushed to the ECR repository

Comment: cool, we did the same at work, but maybe it's way too complicated as the scope of your question.

Comment: okok thanks @Apolozeus. What about if I want to change the tag (e.i. v2.0.0)? There I will have to create another Task correct? And associate the new task to the new tag

Comment: yup, and try use best not to use host port mapping, as it will make things complicated to handle. I use dynamic port + target group (and service discovery) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the image in the Service you can stop and re-run the task or restart the service.

To restart a service:

1. Log into the AWS Management Console.
2. Go to Elastic Container Service.
3. Go to Clusters.
4. Click on the cluster that your service is in.
5. Click on the service you’d like to restart.
6. Click Update.
7. Check Force new deployment about half way down the page.
8. Click Skip to review.
9. Click Update service.
10. Wait patiently as your service restarts!

Or with the cli:

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster :clusterName --service :serviceName --force-new-deployment
```

Credit where credit is due: https://joshtronic.com/2022/04/10/how-to-restart-an-aws-ecs-service/

Answer (score 0):

While update ECS service, you could set "Minimum healthy percent=0" and "Maximum percent=100". This is same as first, stopping currently running task and then launching new task in sequence. This is only option in case of host port mapping.